# How do I expose `UserManager<IApplicationUser>` to my business layer while hiding `IdentityUser`?

Tags: asp.net-identity

I don't want to reference EntityFramework and hence `Identity.EntityFramework` with its `IdentityUser` in my domain. But I'd like to use `UserManager` of `Identity.Core` which uses `IUserStore<TUser>` where `TUser : IUser<string>`. And hence I need to expose that `IUserStore` while hiding `ApplicationUser` as it derives from `IdentityUser`.

In my data access layer:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, IApplicationUser { }

// somewhere for IoC container:
var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>();
// The following breaks with error CS0266: 
//     Cannot implicitly convert type 'UserStore<ApplicationUser>' to 'IUserStore<IApplicationUser>'
IUserStore<IApplicationUser> userStore = userStore;  // does not work
var um = new UserManager<IApplicationUser>(userStore);
```

In my domain layer:

```
public interface IApplicationUser : IUser<string> {}

// desired behavior somewhere in domain/web:
var myUserManager = iocContainer.Resolve<UserManager<IApplicationUser>();
```

This code does not work as TUser in `IUserStore<TUser>` is not variant (covariance).

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't expose UserManager either, as that is coming from an AspNet namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It required me to write an adapter to `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Framework.UserStore` that inherits from `IUserStore` and thus can be used with `UserManager`. It maps my custom user object to IdentityUser. The gist for it can be found at https://gist.github.com/w1ld/b9228f5a27c54b061f90#file-userstoreadapter-cs Hope it helps someone!

Comment: You seem to implement your own ApplicationUserStore - you called it UserStoreAdapter. I am still trying to implement a UserManager with ApplicationUser like the Asp.Net Webapplikation Template does, without implementing everything myself... but i am not there yet :(

Comment: Implementing a new `UserManager` should go smooth. Not sure I understand the difficulty. The problem I had is I didn't want to reference `Identity.EntityFramework` in my project with `UserManager`.

Comment: I am trying something pretty similar. I want to separate IdentityUser (ApplicationUser) into a different project (Entities). Another project should hold the repository and another the WebApi project. This should later make testing easier. If you got a few minutes I am trying this out here: https://github.com/ddNils/TestWebApi02

Comment: @Nils What's required? 1) The point is if your tests should run on database or not. Means if you can go along with EF. I didn't take this way and made it without EF. So I abstracted out `UserStore` using the adapter. Your code now depends on EF: the `IdenityUser`. 2) `UserManager` is more like a business logic and can be independent of `UserStore` and hence from EF. Your version is in `Repo` which is strange. 3) So to make `UserManager` with `ApplicationUser` inherit it from `IUser` if without EF way and remove all EF references. If with EF then I don't see point why not use `UserStore`.

Comment: For me it felt like, when inheriting from Identity - i did get all properties (like UserName or Email). But when inheriting from IUser I had to write all my properties myself. My goal is to not invent the wheel again: Why should I code all user properties, when i only want to add one more?

Comment: Not sure understand the point as the `IdentityUser` is POCO. It doesn't contain any "wheel" invention. And the reason behind it in `..Identity.EF` package is that it needed for `IdentityDbContext` there so that developers can be freed up at all from any coding at that side. See [here](https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/IdentityUser.cs) So when abstracting required it can go without this class.