# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Identity Modifying Primary Key from String to Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-primary-key-configuration?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x) article to modify Primary Key data type of the Identity classes from String to Guid and it does create the `uniqueidentifier` data type for respective columns in the SQL Server instead of the default `NVARCHAR` but I am unable to use the `UserManager` and `SignInManager` classes as they refuse to accept the customized ApplicationUser class  (that extends IdentityUser, as described in the article) instead of the default `IdentityUser` class. 
The article does not go into much detail and by looking at answers to other similar questions on SO 
like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26934374/inherit-from-identityuser-i-get-an-error-on-usermanageruser)  it seems that either I have to change all the classes of the Identity to accomplish this goal or use the 'other' `UserManager` class which I am not entirely sure how to.

My customized Identity models look like this:

```
public class IdentityModels
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
    }
    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid>
    {
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(GetConnectionString());
        }

        private static string GetConnectionString()
        {
            const string databaseName = "testname";
            const string databaseUser = "testuser";
            const string databasePass = "testpass";

            return $"Server=localhost;" +
                   $"database={databaseName};" +
                   $"uid={databaseUser};" +
                   $"pwd={databasePass};" +
                   $"pooling=true;";
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            // Customize the ASP.NET Core Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
            // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Core Identity table names and more.
            // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to change the data type for the Primary Key attribute of the Identity Classes in Identity 2.0 so that `UserManager` and `SignInManager` accept the modifications?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the documentation here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-2.2

You will need to create custom classes that derive from each asp.net identity type which all have a TKey generic parameter which will allow you to specify the type for the primary key. Here are all the signatures of example custom identity classes:

```
public class ApplicationUserToken : IdentityUserToken<Guid> { }
public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<Guid>{ }
public class ApplicationRoleClaim : IdentityRoleClaim<Guid>{ }
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<Guid>{ }
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<Guid>{ }
public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<Guid>{ }
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<Guid> { }
```

Then in your application DB context inherit from IdentityDbContext replacing all the identity classes with the custom ones:

```
public class IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey> : IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, IdentityUserClaim<TKey>, IdentityUserRole<TKey>, IdentityUserLogin<TKey>, IdentityRoleClaim<TKey>, IdentityUserToken<TKey>>
```

Like this:

```
 public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, Guid, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationRoleClaim, ApplicationUserToken> { }
```

Then add this to your Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Last you can run a new migration and update your data base via the console:

`PM> Add-Migration
cmdlet Add-Migration at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Name: Guid-PK
PM> Update-Database -verbose`

Cheers.